# New warnings in XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-2.0

Since I've been using XCode 6 I got some new warnings which I don't quite understand:

- Property type 'UITextView *' is incompatible with type 'NSString *' inherited from 'NSObject'
- 'copy' attribute on property 'description' does not match the property inherited from 'NSObject'
- 'atomic' attribute on property 'description' does not match the property inherited from 'NSObject'

Here the line its related to:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *description;
```

Comment: Please show the code that these warning relate to.

Comment: Sometimes it happens when you try to initialize it in a wrong way. It could happen for you if you are initializing it as a NSString.

Answer (score 3):

`NSObject` has a property with the same name, but a different type - `NSString`, which you are overriding with your own declaration. Change your property name to solve the problem.

Comment: description is the method that is used when you print an object with the %@ format specifier. You don't want to mess with that. You really, really don't want a property named description.